# Wordpress add plugin shows warning and not working contact form 7

Tags: wordpress

I created a wordpress site and added contact form 7, as well as some advanced custom field plugins. I uploaded it to the server. Then the plugins will show active on the Installed plugin tab. But the contact menu does not show in the menu.

Add new plugin will show the following message.

```
Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/excelxrg/public_html/npweb.co.uk/demo2/optimad/maidenhead/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 83
```

Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in the past month (WP4.1 if I remember well). After I have disabled any other plugin I solved downloading contact form 7 from official site https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/
I deleted the old directory from ftp and after that I uploaded the new one, enabled the plugin and everything worked well.
I hope it can help you.